# How to stop in "Too big " to count number s

Tags: javascript, function

In the "Too big" scenario, there should be no counting behavior and the program should end immediately after printing the "Too big" message.

```
var num1 = prompt("Enter the first number"); 
var num2 = prompt("Enter the second number");

console.log("The result is");
var result = ((num1 + num2)*2);{console.log(result);}

if (result < 20) {
  console.log("Too small");

  function countPrint(howMany){ 
    for ( var count = 1; count <= howMany; count++){ 
      console.log(count);
    }
  }
}

countPrint(result);if (result > 20){
  console.log("Too big");
}
```

Comment: You do know that 5 + 0 = 50, yes?

Comment: yes I do know "5" + " 0" = 50

Comment: So you should use `Number(num1) + Number(num2)` or `+num1 + +num2` or `Enter the first digit`

Comment: the question was also asking to *2 that's why  I had to use ((num1 + num2)*2), and it still works, the only problem is I want to stop the counting numbers when the result is "Too big"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soon you enter the `for` loop, it will log all number from your specified `1` to `howMany`, so you need to do something inside the loop and not outside as you are trying to do...

in a `for` loop, you can use `break` to get out of the loop

```
    for (var count = 1; count <= howMany; count++) {
      if (count > 20) break;
      console.log(count);
    }
```

here's an example

```js
const countNumbers = (howMany, maxCount) => {
    console.log('starting counting to', maxCount);
    for (let count = 1; count <= howMany; count++) {
      if (count > maxCount) {
        console.log('the counting %s is higher than the max %s', count, maxCount);
        break; // let's break out of the loop
      }
      console.log('counting ->', count);
    }
}

countNumbers(30, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num1 = prompt("Enter the first number");
var num2 = prompt("Enter the second number");

console.log("The result is");
var result = ((num1 + num2)*2);
//             ^! thise may be strings, should be converted to numbers
{ // why block body? There's no `if` or whatever 
  console.log(result);
}

if (result < 20) {
  console.log("Too small");

  function countPrint(howMany) {
    for (var count = 1; count <= howMany; count++) {
      console.log(count);
    }
  }
}

countPrint(result);
// ^! Cannot find name 'countPrint'.
// function should be outside if
// function is called no matter what the result is

if (result > 20) {
  console.log("Too big");
}
```

As `countPrint(5)` call is not inside `if`, it does not care about if. As `if` is not intide `function ..(..)`, thr function does not care about `if`

```
function countPrint(howMany) {
  for (var count = 1; count <= howMany; count++) {
    console.log(count);
  }
}
if (result <= 20) {
  countPrint(result)
} else {
  console.log(`${result} is Too big`); // <- template string
}
```

```
function countPrint(howMany) {
  if (howMany <= 20) {
    for (var count = 1; count <= howMany; count++) {
      console.log(count);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`${howMany} is Too big`); // <- template string
  }
}
countPrint(result)
```